# Drupal views table with multiple agregation

Tags: views

Is it possible to make drupal views table with multiple agregation like view number 2 below?

```
    1. View Team
+============================+
| Team      |  Sales person  |
|----------------------------|
| Team 1    |  Nick          |
|----------------------------|
| Team 1    |  Jack          |
|----------------------------|
| Team 2    |  Sarah         |
|----------------------------|
| Team 1    |  Joe           |
|----------------------------|
| Team 1    |  Nindya        |
|----------------------------|
| Team 2    |  Octo          |
|============================|
|  Total    |      6         |
+============================+



2. Views with agregation
+============================+
| Team      |  Sales person  |
|----------------------------|
| Team 2    |      2         |
|----------------------------|
| Team 1    |      4         |
|============================|
|  Total    |      6         |
+============================+
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do by using [Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module.

> Sometimes when you use relationships in views you get a number of rows
>   with the same content in some of the fields. This results in a huge
>   table (grid, list, etc.) that affects the usability of your view. The
>   Views Merge Rows module provides a way to combine rows with the same
>   content in the specified fields.